# WMTS problem in QGIS

Tags: qgis, wmts

I have a problem using a Web Map Tiling Services in QGIS.
Here you can see the address of the service: https://wmts.geo.admin.ch/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml?lang=fr

I can easily add it through the "Data Source Manager" and I have all my different tilesets. If I load one of them from the "Data Source Manager", a window appears where I need to set a dimension (time).
[image]

It works perfectly...

But now, if I go in my browser panel, I also have all my tilesets.

[image]

But if I load a data from the browser panel, the layer is empty?

If we look the source in the properties of the layers, we can see that they are also different:

- The one who works:
  [image]
- The one who doesn't work:
  [image]

Did anyone have an idea, so I can load my data from my browser panel? It is boring to go in the "Data Source Manager"...

Comment: So the main reason dragging the layer doesn't display it is because there's an additional keyword argument for `TIME`, and without it the layer isn't rendered. Unfortunately, unlike through the data source manager interface, this additional input is not prompted, and I haven't been able to to change the `source` in layer properties... If somehow helpful PyQGIS should be able to do this (but doubt this is easier than just going to data source manager)